# Divide personal names in separate columns

Tags: sql-server, substring

I have one table which is called #MyNames.This table in one column contain full name of persons (Name space Surname). In this column we can distinct name from surname with space with them.From left side we have name and after space we have surname.Below you can see table:

[image]

So my intention is to divided this column with name MyFullName into two separate columns called ,,FirstName" and ,,LastName''. In order to do this i try with this code:

```
SELECT LEFT(MyFullName,charindex(' ', MyFullName) - 1) AS FirstName, RIGHT(MyFullName,charindex(' ', MyFullName)-1 )  AS LastName
from #MyNames
```

Output from this code is not good and I have results like table below :

[image]

So can anybody help me how to fix this code and get result correctly and to have fist name in one column and second name in other column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously the surname clause isn't working correctly.

Instead of using `RIGHT(MyFullName,charindex(' ', MyFullName)-1 )` consider `SUBSTRING(MyFullName,charindex(' ', MyFullName) + 1, 100)` (or whatever field length is).

A better approach (though less easy to read imo) is to replace the first name component with blank '' characters.
`STUFF(MyFullName,1,charindex(' ', MyFullName),'')`

These should both work

```
SELECT LEFT(MyFullName,charindex(' ', MyFullName)-1) AS FirstName,
       SUBSTRING(MyFullName,charindex(' ', MyFullName)+1, 100) AS LastName
from #MyNames

SELECT LEFT(MyFullName,charindex(' ', MyFullName)-1) AS FirstName,
       STUFF(MyFullName,1,charindex(' ', MyFullName),'') AS LastName
from #MyNames
```

Answer (score 1):

A small correction in your query should fix the problem.

```
SELECT LEFT(MyFullName,charindex(' ', MyFullName) - 1) AS FirstName
     , RIGHT(MyFullName,len(MyFullName) - charindex(' ', MyFullName))  AS LastName
from #MyNames
```

Comment: Beware using `LEN` for these. I've found (from personal experience) that `LEN` ignores trailing spaces. See this [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=dbc09da953d9ff9030e51feab259efb8). Of course, all these solutions are vulnerable to the data not being cleaned properly.